# Is there any API to create map with gps and indoor positioning?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-gps, indoor-positioning-system

Is there any API where can i upload my map and use GPS with indoor using wifi im trying to create a mobile app where i need GPS and a Wifi for localization i dont know where to start can someone give me advices. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use google maps widgets for map

https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

and for current location, you can use GeoLocator Plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator